# Why does cats returns `Id[T]` in the evaluation of a Reader?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, scala-cats

I've used `Kleisli` before and, when you evaluate the computation passing the dependency to it the monad returns the value that I need.
Now I'm using `Reader` and I see that when I run the program the evaluation is returned wrapped in an `Id`.

Why?

Also, exploring the different options that `Id` has I encountered with `init` function that unwraps the computed value. Is it good to use that "combinator"? The only thing that I need from the `Reader` is the produced value without any wrapper.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Id` is defined as `type Id[A] = A`. So it's just the type itself, and you can use it as if there was no `Id` there.

The following code is valid:

```
val s: Id[String] = "123"
s.charAt(s.length - 1)
```

As `cats` documentation states:

> Identity, encoded as `type Id[A] = A`, a convenient alias to make identity instances well-kinded.
>
> The identity monad can be seen as the ambient monad that encodes the effect of having no effect. It is ambient in the sense that plain pure values are values of `Id`.
>
> For instance, the `cats.Functor` instance for `cats.Id` allows us to apply a function `A => B` to an `Id[A]` and get an
>   `Id[B]`. However, an `Id[A]` is the same as `A`, so all we're doing
>   is applying a pure function of type `A => B` to a pure value  of
>   type `A` to get a pure value of type `B`. That is, the instance
>   encodes pure unary function application.

For instance, for `Reader` it's more convenient to define it as:

```
type Reader[A, B] = ReaderT[Id, A, B]
type ReaderT[F[_], A, B] = Kleisli[F, A, B]
```

This allows you to define all the typeclass instances for the more complex case when `F[_]` is something real, and just use those instances for the simpler case when there is no `F[_]` (i.e., when `F` is `Id`).